# tests inside function calls or for statements in clojure not running

Tags: testing, clojure, clojurescript

I wrote code that looks something like this

```
(testing "check that for all these roles there's an alert"
    (binding [*profile* account-exceeded-limits]
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role readonly-no-download)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role dataentry)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role editor)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role member)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role collaborator)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role readonly)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))))
```

I need to refactor this code to make it drier.

So I tried this

```
(testing "check that for all these roles theres an alert"
    (for [role [dataentry readonly-no-download editor member collaborator
             readonly]]
      (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role role)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning")))))
```

It seemed that tests were not ran.

I also tried this:

```
(testing "check that for all these roles theres an alert"
(map (fn [role]  (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form
                                              :role role)]
        (is (dommy/has-class?
             (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body
                                      :.alert]))
             "alert-warning"))) [dataentry readonly-no-download editor member collaborator
             readonly])))
```

again, it still seemed that tests were not ran.

What could be causing this? is there a way I can make this test dryer? should I be trying to make tests dryer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Clojure, the `for` and `map` functions are both lazy, and won't run until you do something with the output.

Since you don't care about the output, you should convert the `for` into a `doseq`, which always runs right away (non-lazy) and is intended for side-effects like you want here.

Be sure to also bookmark [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) and always keep it open in a browser tab!

There are also many other [great resources listed here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

---

**Appendix**:

A very useful cousin to `map` is `mapv`.  It is nothing more than `(vec (map ...))`, which forces the output of `map` into a (non-lazy) vector.  I had been using Clojure for quite a while before I first heard about it.

You can similarly get a non-lazy version of `for` by using `(vec (for ...))`.  It runs immediately like `doseq`, but also returns the result sequence (instead of just `nil`). You can see [more details here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#focus-on-vectors).

Comment: thanks, I'm bookmarking the closure CheatSheet for sure!

Answer (score 5):

While the reason your code is not running is already taken care of, I'd like to point out [`are`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/are)

> ```
> (are argv expr & args)
>
> Checks multiple assertions with a template expression.
> See clojure.template/do-template for an explanation of
> templates.
>  Example: (are [x y] (= x y)  
>               2 (+ 1 1)
>               4 (* 2 2))
> Expands to: 
>          (do (is (= 2 (+ 1 1)))
>              (is (= 4 (* 2 2))))
>  Note: This breaks some reporting features, such as line numbers.
> ```

Which would allow for something like:

```clj
(testing "check that for all these roles there's an alert"
  (are [role] 
       (let [overview-page (overview-container sample-form :role role)]
         (dommy/has-class?
           (-> overview-page (sel1 [:div#export-list-panel :.panel-body :.alert]))
           "alert-warning"))
       dataentry 
       readonly-no-download 
       editor 
       member 
       collaborator 
       readonly))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd also like to link this article on `are` here: https://fpsd.codes/clojure-bites---clojuretestare.html